# How can I save all field data using customer_save_before event. I was able to receive all field data but I could not save it

Tags: magento2

I want to save all user input field data in uppercase in the database. I was able to receive all field data but I could not save it. Please guide me how to do it. 
This is event file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_save_before">
        <observer name="customer_address_save_before_observer" instance="ABCD\XYZ\Observer\CustomerData\CustomerDataPost" />
    </event>
</config>
```

This is observer file

```
<?php
namespace ABCD\XYZ\Observer\CustomerData\CustomerDataPost;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class CustomerDataPost implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request

    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customerdata=$this->request->getPost();
        $customerdata['lastname']= strtoupper($customerdata['lastname']);
        $this->request->setPostValue('lastname',$customerdata['lastname']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then Injecting `RequestInterface` you can get the customer data on `$observer` object, and set the value from there. like this,

```
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        $lastName = $customer->getLastName();
        $customer->setLastName(strtoupper($lastName));
```

Comment: @Saha, thank you for giving answer, would you like to tell me how i able to also  update customer address information through customer_save_before event and update all information to uppercase.

Comment: could you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694678/active-an-extension-based-on-condition-in-magento-2